# Android Choosing NavGraph in the Activity

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I have a simple activity which looks like this

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph_A" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

I have two different navigation XML which have the following logic:
**Navigation XML A** starts in which the starting fragment has a button which if we press **Navigation XML B** kicks in which has another default start destination and recieves a number in the form of SafeArgs (veryNiceNumber: Int) - so we navigate between two navigation graph and **Navigation XML A** navigates to **Navigation XML B** so they have a connection.

What i would like to achieve is this:
I do not want to hardcode the default navGraph. I would like to use some logic to choose which navigation XML gets inflated first.

If the logic chooses **Navigation XML B** i want to send a random number to the safeArgs

This is the closest i got to the solution:

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
    val navController = navHostFragment.navController

    val inflater = navController.navInflater
    val graph = inflater.inflate(R.navigation.nav_graph_B)
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putString("veryNiceNumber", "12")
    graph.addInDefaultArgs(bundle)
    navController.graph = graph
}
```

It navigets to the **Navigation XML B** but the navArgs throws an error as it doesnt recognise the bundle as navArgs.

I also tried to extract it like this: requireActivity().intent.extras but it is empty.

(Extra task: if the user presses the back button in **Navigation XML B** it navigates to **Navigation XML A**)

Comment: What is the drive for requiring having different default nav graphs? Is the inflation of it such an issue?

Comment: @TheLibrarian Long story short: When a certian Push Notification arrives i would like to open Navigation XML B - The push notification already contains the ID which i have to use in Navigation XML B. Usually the user starts at Navigation XML A then navaiges to Navigation XML B but this time it is differente